# OpenCV - suppress, hide or disable the error or warning messages outputted to the screen

Tags: python, opencv, ffmpeg

I was wondering if there was a way to suppress, hide or disable the error or warning messages outputted to the screen from OpenCV, I think originating from cap.read()?

I think they come from OpenCV using FFMpeg and they either show up as follows:

CASE 1:

```
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
[mpeg2video @ 0x3430c00] Invalid frame dimensions 0x0.
```

or

CASE 2:

```
...
[h264 @ 0x29e5a40] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x2a6c3c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x29d7b80] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x29d7b80] Missing reference picture, default is 65656
[h264 @ 0x298da80] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x298da80] number of reference frames (0+6) exceeds max (5; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x29dc700] reference picture missing during reorder
[h264 @ 0x29dc700] Missing reference picture, default is 65672
[h264 @ 0x2a27180] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x2af7680] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x29e5a40] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x29e5a40] number of reference frames (0+6) exceeds max (5; probably corrupt input), discarding one
[h264 @ 0x2af9040] mmco: unref short failure
```

To my understanding CASE 1, is a known issue, as it is looking for a PES header. There are only a few of these messages until it finds the header.

I do not understand CASE 2, I do not know what is happening, but it seems to read the image @ frame. There are many many of these messages which outputs to the console window and adds minutes to the processing time.

Comment: The 2nd case are from the h264 parser and indicates a corrupt stream or missing packets. ffmpeg logs to stderr although OpenCV is probably redirecting it.

Comment: @Gyan Instead of using OpenCV, do you know if another library like ffmpeg-python, pyav or even using FFMpeg using subprocess could I suppress these messages?  In the end, I just need frames grabs from a video as quickly as possible and not married to OpenCV since these message add addition process time.

Comment: Using ffmpeg directly, you can add `-v 0` to suppress most messages.

Answer (score -1):

See [Enable OpenCV ffmpeg logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269745/enable-opencv-ffmpeg-logging)

```
   os.environ['OPENCV_LOG_LEVEL'] = 'OFF'
   os.environ['OPENCV_FFMPEG_LOGLEVEL'] = "-8"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34670467)